# My github download raw button is not working, no matter how many times i click that button

Tags: github

i want to download some specific files on github and my raw button not works and I have to download whole repo to download that specific repo.
[image]

What is the solution??

I want that working download raw button and it is not working for some time and this problem exists in every browser

Comment: Open your developer tools, navigate to the network tab, check the "preserve log" box, and reload the page. See if any requests are being blocked. Then (with the tools still open), click the download raw button. This will help isolate the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, clicking the download icon would not work as I was connected to the internet through wi-fi through a dongle provided through a mobile provider. Once I changed to a wi-fi connection provided through an Internet Service Provider (ISP), clicking the download icon proceeded with the actual download.

Answer (score -1):

Connect to a *VPN* or something different internet provider other than your default one.